# Computational Geometry open source lib

Tags: c#, dll, computational-geometry

does anyone know an open source c# dll for Computational Geometry.

Comment: i missed explaining, i meant a dll that is compatible with c#: however, i think LEDA or CGAL are not free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't much out there, unfortunately -- the .NET world seems to suffer from a paucity of good open-source math libraries. The best readily available commercial alternative is probably [**Ceometric's G#**](http://www.ceometric.com/products/g.html), which is neither free nor open-source.

Answer (score 4):

I'm starting an open-source Computational Geometry library for .NET here: https://github.com/govert/RobustGeometry.NET.

So far I have the robust geometric predicates of Shewchuk ported to C#, and I'm working on a helfedge mesh representation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

aforgenet library originally meant for image processing/computer vision/ machine learning AI , does have some good deal of features that can help you!
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/

Answer (score 0):

There is a library named Geolib at  http://www.geolib.co.uk/.
I am just starting to use it and till now its works fine for me!